# Как сделать кнопку для каждой строки Таблицы?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Всем доброй ночи/дня.
разбираюсь с google app script, и стоит перед мною задание:

В таблице Аркуш1, в столбце "С" сделать кнопку, при нажатии которой создается **Шаблонный документ**(я назвал его *newDocTemplate*) (template),где поля с инф о кленте и автомобиле автоматом берутся из Аркуш1
Строго говоря newDocTemplate - это копия template, **но** с заполненными некоторыми ячейками, взятыми из таблицы **LIST**

Я это вроде как сделал, но только для 1-го клиента. Но мне надо что бы при клике на строчку(с кнопкой) С5, С6, и т.д. создавался документ с соответствующими клиентами. Кнопку я реализовал в виде меню.

Может кто поможет мне с этим вопросом.

Вот код:

```js
var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
// получаем активный документ(все листы)
var template = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("template"); // выносим в переменную базовцй шаблон заявки
var newTable = activeSreadsheet.setActiveSheet(template).copyTo(activeSreadsheet).activate(); // создаем шаблон в новый лист, и кладем в активный документ и сразу его делаем активным
var dataSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("Аркуш1"); // берем таблицу с данными

function addNewTable(rIndx){
  var data = { // решил создать объект с данными 
    model: dataSheet.getRange("D" +rIndx).getValue(),
    cantact: dataSheet.getRange("E" +rIndx).getValue()
  }
  newTable.getRange("A9").setValue("Замовник, тел.: "+data.cantact).setFontWeight("bold");
  newTable.getRange("A10").setValue("Марка і модель авто: " + data.model).setFontWeight("bold");
}

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("myMenu")
  .addItem("Generate new Tamplate", "addNewTable")
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem("ID", "onEdit")
  .addToUi();
}

function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() // Получаем имя листа который активен 
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();//Ячейка в которой произошло изменение
  var rowIndex = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //var _sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];//Лист где нужно изменения отлавливать
  var activeCELL = dataSheet.getActiveCell();
  var activeCELL_index = i.getRowIndex();
  addNewTable(activeCELL_index);
//  Logger.log(rowIndex)
}
```

[Ссылка на GoogleDocs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XGHwhggxBTwuKb65qXzgIC4UADMQLg3ele8k7xzKOwY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал как:

- перенес бы глобальные переменные в начале внутрь функции `addNewTable`. Копирование шаблона и активирование его в глобальном контексте «сбивает» выбор активной ячейки — это всегда будет ячейка А1 самого нового листа, в которой, конечно, нет нужных значений.
- функция `onEdit` здесь не нужна; насколько я понимаю, вызов из меню делает всю работу.

Получается примерно так:

```
function addNewTable() {
  var activeSreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // получаем активный документ(все листы)
  var template = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("template"); // выносим в переменную базовцй шаблон заявки
  var newTable = template.copyTo(activeSreadsheet); // создаем шаблон в новый лист, и кладем в активный документ
  var dataSheet = activeSreadsheet.getSheetByName("Аркуш1"); // берем таблицу с данными
  var rIndx = dataSheet.getActiveRange().getRow(); //считываем номер активной строки
  var data = { // решил создать объект с данными 
    model: dataSheet.getRange("D" +rIndx).getValue(),
    cantact: dataSheet.getRange("E" +rIndx).getValue()
  }
  newTable.getRange("A9").setValue("Замовник, тел.: "+data.cantact).setFontWeight("bold");
  newTable.getRange("A10").setValue("Марка і модель авто: " + data.model).setFontWeight("bold");
  newTable.activate(); //активируем скопированный лист
}

function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("myMenu")
  .addItem("Generate new Tamplate", "addNewTable")
  .addToUi();
}
```

UPD
Если все-таки нужно имитировать нажатие кнопки через изменение значения ячейки в определенной колонке, можно сделать так:

```
function onEdit(event){
  Logger.log(event);
  //если была изменена колонка «С» в нужном листе, вызвать выполнение функции addNewTable
  if (event.range.getColumn() === 3 && event.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Аркуш1') { 
    addNewTable(event.range.getRow());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо кнопки программно вставляйте в ячейку каждой строки чек-бокс. При изменеии чек-бокса у вас будет срабатывать скрипт по onEdit. других вариантов в через ванильный GS не сделать. Я сделал работает.
Или пишите расширение для браузера, которое будет через DOM определять строку и  запускать GS.